# how to keep the value of a cookie

Tags: go

I am in the process of user authentication in my application which is done through a cookie that the jwt saves, when I make the request the client obtains the cookie without problems, but when the client updates the page or only f5 the cookie is deleted , I was investigating if it was happening on localhost or there was a problem in my code, but I didn't find anything related to my problem.
This is my code in Go:

```
func Login(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    u := model.User{}
    if err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&u); err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "format incorrect", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    user, equals, err := u.AccessControll(u.Email, u.Password)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    if !equals {
        http.Error(w, "ups", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    token, err := jwt.CreateToken(user)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    cookie := http.Cookie{
        Name:     "token",
        Value:    token,
        Expires:  time.Now().Add(5 * time.Minute),
        HttpOnly: true,
    }

    http.SetCookie(w, &cookie)
}
```

Comment: If you can solve the problem, I did not know that MaxAge was more necessary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Browsers default the cookie path to the request path. Browsers do not send a cookie if the cookie path is not a path prefix of the request path.  The cookie in the question is only set for requests to the login handler path and paths below that.

Set the cookie path to "/" to make the cookie available on all paths.

This is probably unrelated, but it's better to set MaxAge instead of Expires because MaxAge is unaffected by clock skew.

```
cookie := http.Cookie{
    Name:     "token",
    Value:    token,
    Path:     "/",
    MaxAge:   5 * 60,
    HttpOnly: true,
}
```